# opening text file in my textapp

Tags: java, swing, io, jtextpane

I am new in java swing .For practice, I've created text app which simply allow the user to open,read and write text files and also have some editing functions.
I've packaged my .class and other required files into jar file and created **.exe** file from this jar file.

When user opens text file(.txt,.rtf e.t.c) from the app(by clicking **Open file** toolbar on my app ) it works fine and display the content of file in JTextpane.

But when user opens text file outside my app (by clicking **open with** and set my app to open particular text file)  to display the content of file on my app,my app just getting opened but not displaying the content of the file in JTextPane .

Can anyone suggest me  the way How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you **Open With...** a file, that file's location is passed to the program as the first argument. So in your `public static void main(String... args)` procedure, you could add handling of a first argument that is a file location and open that file as you would otherwise from the GUI.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to do this? BTW thanks for your answer

Comment: I would recommend you check the first argument passed to the program is a string and that it points to a valid file (a file that exists and is a text file), and then store the filename in a variable somewhere. Then do your normal Swing processing and have an onCreation method/event that sets the contents of your JContentPane to the contents of the file.